# Seems Cron job working even after Stopped

Tags: php, linux, cron

one of my cronjobs send an email daily

```
35 6 * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q 2>&1
```

I stopped cron using

```
sudo service cron stop
```

when i check the cron status

```
 sudo service cron status
```

it is `cron stop/waiting`

the problem is i stopped my crons yesterday , but today also the email was sent again

am i doing this wrong

```
1.how to stop all cron jobs properly 
2.how to view last ran cronjob list .
```

i tried to get last ran cronob details by

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

but it is empty , but when i go to the `syslog` file i can see the word `CRON` in some places .

```
Aug 12 09:10:01 64177 CRON[6388]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www && /usr/bin/php runcronjobs.p......
```

also when i tries typing

ps -ax|grep cron

```
 5696 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cron
13011 ?        Ss     0:00 cron l
```

is it possble to run crons after i stopped the cron jobs ??

Thanks in advnace

Comment: Just comment out the cronjob to stop it. `# 0 0 0 0` ...

Comment: @l'L'l so you are saing sudo service cron stop is not working :-o

Comment: I've never used it the way you are trying — I always use `crontab`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do it is to put every job or every group of jobs in their own 'namespace' / file:

```
/etc/cron.d/production-job-mail-on-delivery
/etc/cron.d/production-aggregate-account-data
/etc/cron.d/devel-job-mail-on-delivery
/etc/cron.d/system-cleanup-sundy
/etc/cron.d/common-mailings
```

When you want to stop, you just move those files out of the `/etc/cron.d/` folder.

You should not stop the cron service and you shouldn't use `crontab` / `/etc/crontab` on a bigger system.

Why?

For example, I have 200 cronjobs on a system. `/etc/crontab` file gets very messy. Some jobs need to be stopped for a week for example, others need to run permanently. Using `cron.d` folder this is a very simple task.

Comment: ...and to think you worked hard to get that job...!  I see this was written 4 years ago so I hope you've figured out an elegant scheme for this, or have delegated it out entirely.  Often I believe the best method is SEP - make it Somebody Else's Problem.  Anyway, Upvote for the visual.  Mine is already more than a pageful and I don't like that I can't visualize when they all run.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would access your crontab with:

```
crontab -l (lists cronjobs)
```

and to edit:

```
crontab -e
```

to stop a cronjob temporarily you can usually just comment out the first digit:

```
# 35 6 * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q 2>&1
```

to no longer run a cronjob permanently just delete the particular job. crontab usually restarts itself automatically after you edit it. if not trying using:

```
sudo restart cron
```

more information: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do it is commenting the cronjob trough a crontab -e:

```
#35 6 * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q 2>&1
```

Other than that you should configure the time the frequency of the cronjob to run.

To stop processes you can

```
ps|aux grep runcronjobs
```

and after you get a list of the processes runing you can just kill a process using its number

```
kill *number
```